# Sending data from Javascript/HTML to php to conduct search

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to implement a simple search engine using php. Should I have a .php continuously running on my server and post say a JSON OR could I somehow post something to the server and have the script run only when something is posted? Either way I don't know how to do either. I've also been reading something about CRON jobs. Does that apply here?

EDIT: Users sees search box. Types in query into search box. Presses enter. JSON query sent using AJAX to server. Server uses JSON query sent to search the indices of certain documents, not to search the website. The server returns results in JSON format. These results are then interpreted and displayed to the user.

I already have the search setup in php. I'm fairly new to php.

EDIT2: I already have the search setup using Elastic Search. I just wanted to know what was best practice in sending information from Javascript/HTML site to pHp on a server. I apologize for not being clear enough.

Comment: What are you trying to search for/within? What have you tried?

Comment: FYI PHP isn't a great solution to this problem

Comment: All I need to do is send the server a few words in JSON format and the server interprets that and conducts a search and sends results in response.

Comment: A search *where*? Within what kind of data? You really need to be more precise if you want a good answer.

Comment: @Anonymous what does "conducts a search" even mean? please be very specific

Comment: It conducts a search on the server, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Yeah, but *where*? Among a set of files? In a database?

Comment: @Anonymous what kinda of search, are you searching mysql, are you searching flat text files, an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRON jobs wouldn't apply unless you would want to schedule the searches and notify your users when the search is done (even though it's possible, it's not really what you're looking for).

AJAX is quite handy here especially if you'd like to add such functionality as autocompletion. However if you're expecting the page to reload, re-rendering the whole page contents with the search results or redirecting to another page with those results, AJAX isn't necessary, because you'd have to do 2 HTTP requests rather than just one.

In my opinion, all you need to do is have a single-input form with the search field posting via a GET request.

So for instance:

```
<form action="/search_results.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="query" />
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Which would do a redirect to the search results page with the URL as something like this: /search_results.php?query=some+simple+search

Then, within your PHP code you can fetch that query parameter using $_GET['query'] which you can directly pass to your search engine (Elastic Search) to analyse.

I haven't ever tried Elastic Search, but if you must pass JSON data, you can just encode the query using:

```
$search = json_encode(array('query' => $_GET['query']));
```

It's hard to be precise because you haven't provided the expected format for the search, but I think this should get you on track.

Feel free to comment below if you have any questions :)

Comment: Great. But, how would I pass back the data in a JSON?

Comment: But why does the returned data have to be in JSON anyway? Do you really want to render the result on the Client-side rather than Server-side where you get the JSON response from the Search Engine?

Comment: You're probably right. When submitting though, how would I prevent the entire page from refreshing? I just want some content on the page to be changed. Similar to Google.

Comment: Ok, then in that case you do need to use AJAX. Have a dedicated page just for handling the search, but instead of submitting the form do what liding suggested in his post. Simplest solution would be to use jQuery's $.load function which would replace the contents of the selected element with the contents returned by the request - which means that you should render the results server-side (in your PHP script) and echo them out. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Don't you think that it would be faster to send just data rather than an entire element?

Comment: I think that depends on the amount of traffic you can handle. Even with high traffic I doubt you'd notice it :)

Comment: Do you think I could do anything else to speed it up?

Comment: Is it slow already? :) Have you benchmarked it? Otherwise don't bother. In most cases the bottleneck will be your database not the application.

Comment: I wanted to do something similar to google instant, so I'll take any performance boost I can get.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<form method="get" action="search.php>
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

search.php:

```
<?php

$whatTheyWantToSearch = $_GET['search'];

// $whatTheyWantToSearch now holds the value that was submitted in the form
```

Comment: That's quite a partial answer, considering the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm"> 
    <input id="request" type="text" size="20"><br/><br/>  
    <input type="submit" value="search">  
</form>  

<div id="search_result"></div>  

<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){  

        $('#myForm').submit(function(){  
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "search.php",  
                data: "search_request="+$("#request").val(),  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#search_result").html(html);  
                }  
            });  
            return false;  
        });  

    });  
</script>
```